# If I create/assign shared memory in one function, I can use it inside the function I call after can't I?

Tags: memory, scope, cuda, shared

So, if I have a **device** (or **global**) function that creates/copies some data into shared memory and I later call another **device** function, like so:

```
__global__ void a(){ 
    __shared__ int blah=0;
    fun();
}
__device__ void fun(){
   blah = 1; //perform some operations
   //do whatever
}
```

I'm a bit rusty with my CUDA, I think you might have had to "redefine" shared variable (I assume the operation checked if a shared variable of that name exists, if so assigns it) - this had the effect of creating context - so basically the variable didn't just come out of nowhere. Alternatively, if it's similar to having a global variable in standard C/C++ and I can just reference it, like I did above, it'd be great.

**I am familiar with memory hierarchy, I'm just rusty on the semantics of creating/referencing memory.**

Please advise on whether the above sketch would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that won't work in CUDA, any more that it would work in standard C99. Currently, the preferred method of `__device__` function compilation is inline expansion (they are also compiled as standalone code objects for the Fermi architecture), but even so `__device__` functions still must obey standard syntax and scope conventions of C99. So you need to pass arguments which don't have compilation unit scope by reference to `__device__` functions.

Comment: But, when you have multiple threads - you can't pass a reference, each thread tries to assign a shared memory of that name, consequently all threads in the block can have access to the __shared__ variable.

Comment: Of course you can pass a reference to a shared memory variable to a device function and it is completely valid to do so. For _correctness_ reasons, your contrived example would not be done unconditionally, but what happens at run time and what happens at compile time are totally separate issues.